# Autofilter column of data in table on a different tab

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter the data in column A on sheet 1 and return multiple values at the same time. I have the following code that works excellent but only searches by "C4" in sheet 2, I would like the filter to show everything in C4:C20. Any suggestions?

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
    Dim sInput  As String
    sInput = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C4").Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A60000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & sInput & "*"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use the "array" *flavour* of `AutoFilter()` method

```
Dim sInput  As Variant

sInput = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C4:C20").Value)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A60000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sInput, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried the code but it don't like the last line, Any suggestions?

Comment: @RobertG, did you get through it?

Comment: Good day, After digging into some of my old sheets I was able to come up with a code that worked. the last piece is to get it to filter out blanks, perhaps you could take a look.

 Dim Criteria_Val(100) As String
    Dim iRow As Integer
 
    iRow = 0
    While Sheets("Query").Cells(iRow + 1, 2) <> ""
        Criteria_Val(iRow) = Sheets("Query").Cells(iRow + 1, 4)
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Wend
 
    Sheets(1).Range("J1:J3000").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Criteria_Val, Operator:=xlFilterValues